# Dar de alta un evento y hacer tracking de clic con google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

quisiera saber como dar de alta un evento en Google Analytics para realizar el tracking de un botón.

Anteriormente me pasaban los parametros para yo ponerlos en un JS y así trackear el evento de un click. 
Lo manejo así en el javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#button-track").on("click", function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
     ga('send', {
       hitType: 'event',
       eventCategory: 'buttons_blue',
       eventAction: 'click',
       eventLabel: 'boton azul',
    });  
  }, 3000);
 });
});
```

Y anteriormente yo no configuraba nada en analytics solo me dedicaba a pasar eso a JS mas sin embargo ahora me enfrento al problema de que el tracking no se realiza y quizas es porque me falta configurar algo en el panel de analytics pero no veo alguna opción para añadir eventos.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: a la derecha del panel-> tiempo real -> eventos, si no aparece fijate debajo de todo hay filtros (administrar propiedades o vistas) si lo estas viendo como invitado puede que no tengas permisos, ó que la propiedad esté filtrando los dominios desde los cuales recibe eventos

Comment: Pero no me aparece una opción para crear evento, solo me muestra los eventos actuales

Comment: es que no se crean, a lo sumo se filtran para que no aparezcan, el código de seguimiento esta bien? dice algo la consola de desarrollador del navegador? en la pestaña de red deberías poder ver las peticiones del ga y el ok